# Read collection from another html

Tags: javascript, html

.Hello

If I have links collection in my html file:

```
<UL class="collection-o-links" style="list-style-type:none">
 <LI><a href="page1.html"> Page A </a></LI>
 <LI><a href="page2.html"> Page B </a></LI>
 <LI><a href="page3.html"> Page C </a></LI>
</UL>
```

and to  read JavaScript in same html, not `.js` :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var links = $(".collection-o-links li");

  // some code
}
</script>
```

My question if it is possible to read `collection-o-links` listed in one html document into the another html document JavaScript.

Comment: how is it referenced? by an iframe? is it another file?

Comment: @isaac hello, yes it is  same file in this case,  and I'm asking about reading from another. for example read list from page_b.html  into page_a.html  with JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this fairly easily using jQuery's **[`get` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)**:

```js
$.get('second_page.html', null, function(text) {
    console.log($(text).find(".collection-o-links li"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, without the reliance on jQuery, this can be done with JavaScript's **[`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)** method:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
  console.log(evt);
}, false);

request.open('GET', 'second_page.html', true),
  request.send();
```

Note that the [**`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header must be present on the second page in order to use either method.

Hope this helps! :)